# How to unescape special characters from BeautifulSoup output?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, beautifulsoup

I am facing issues with the special characters like ° and ® which represent the  degree Fahrenheit sign and the registered sign,

when i print the string the contains the special characters, it gives output like this:

```
Preheat oven to 350&deg; F
Welcome to Lorem Ipsum Inc&reg;
```

Is there a way I can output the exact characters and not their codes? Please let me know.

Comment: Can you post some code that we can run that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: -1 for not including _any_ code.

Comment: You should remove the code you put in the comments below and put it into your question instead; also you should mark it as code so it will display properly (select the block and press Ctrl+K). I've taken the liberty to edit your post a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ python -c'from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
> print BeautifulSoup("""<html>Preheat oven to 350&deg; F
> Welcome to Lorem Ipsum Inc&reg;""",
> convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES).contents[0].string'
Preheat oven to 350° F
Welcome to Lorem Ipsum Inc®
```

Comment: sorry, please don't get me wrong, all i want is to get the symbols, of the registered  and the degree celsius. i'll try the one mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian that solved my issue, and thanks David for co-operating with me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script which for tolerant unescaping of HTML references from web pages - it assumes that the references are e.g. in `&deg;` format with a semicolon after them though (`Preheat oven to 350&deg; F` for example):

```
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint

# Get the whitespace characters
nums_dict = {0: ' ', 1: '\t', 2: '\r', 3: '\n'}
chars_dict = dict((x, y) for y, x in nums_dict.items())
nums_dict2XML = {0: '&#32;', 1: '&#09;', 2: '&#13;', 3: '&#10;'}
chars_dict2XML = dict((nums_dict[i], nums_dict2XML[i]) for i in nums_dict2XML)

s = '1234567890ABCDEF'
hex_dict = {}
for i in s:
    hex_dict[i.lower()] = None
hex_dict[i.upper()] = None
del s

def is_hex(s):
    if not s:
        return False

    for i in s:
        if i not in hex_dict:
            return False
    return True

class Unescape:
    def __init__(self, s, ignore_whitespace=False):
        # Converts HTML character references into a unicode string to allow manipulation
        self.s = s
        self.ignore_whitespace = ignore_whitespace
        self.lst = self.process(ignore_whitespace)

    def process(self, ignore_whitespace):
        def get_char(c):
            if ignore_whitespace:
                return c
            else:
                if c in chars_dict:
                    return chars_dict[c]
                else: return c

        r = []
        lst = self.s.split('&')
        xx = 0
        yy = 0
        for item in lst:
            if xx:
                split = item.split(';')
                if split[0].lower() in name2codepoint:
                    # A character reference, e.g. '&amp;'
                    a = unichr(name2codepoint[split[0].lower()])
                    r.append(get_char(a)) # TOKEN CHECK?
                    r.append(';'.join(split[1:]))

                elif split[0] and split[0][0] == '#' and split[0][1:].isdigit():
                    # A character number e.g. '&#52;'
                    a = unichr(int(split[0][1:]))
                    r.append(get_char(a))
                    r.append(';'.join(split[1:]))

                elif split[0] and split[0][0] == '#' and split[0][1:2].lower() == 'x' and is_hex(split[0][2:]):
                    # A hexadecimal encoded character
                    a = unichr(int(split[0][2:].lower(), 16)) # Hex -> base 16
                    r.append(get_char(a))
                    r.append(';'.join(split[1:]))

                else:
                    r.append('&%s' % ';'.join(split))
            else:
                r.append(item)
            xx += 1
            yy += len(r[-1])
        return r

def get_value(self):
    # Convert back into HTML, preserving
    # whitespace if self.ignore_whitespace is `False`
    r = []
    for i in self.lst:
        if type(i) == int:
            r.append(nums_dict2XML[i])
        else:
            r.append(i)
    return ''.join(r)

def unescape(s):
    # Get the string value from escaped HTML `s`, ignoring
    # explicit whitespace like tabs/spaces etc
    inst = Unescape(s, ignore_whitespace=True)
    return ''.join(inst.lst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print unescape('Preheat oven to 350&deg; F')
print unescape('Welcome to Lorem Ipsum Inc&reg;')
```

**EDIT:** Here's a simpler solution which only replaces the character references with characters and not `&#xx;` references:

```
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint

def unescape(s):
    for name in name2codepoint:
        s = s.replace('&%s;' % name, unichr(name2codepoint[name]))
    return s

print unescape('Preheat oven to 350&deg; F')
print unescape('Welcome to Lorem Ipsum Inc&reg;')
```

Comment: recipeDiv= BeautifulSoup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'preparation'})       
        recipeDiv= str(recipeDiv)
        recipeDiv= BeautifulSoup(recipeDiv)
        RN= len(recipeDiv('p'))
        y=0
        while (y < RN):
            recipeDivDict= {}
            recipeDivText= str(strip_tags(recipeDiv('p')[y]))
            recipeDivText= recipeDivText.strip()
            recipeDivText= recipeDivText.strip('\n')
            print recipeDivText
            recipeDivDict['directions']= recipeDivText
            RecipeList.append(recipeDivDict)
            y = y + 1

Comment: when i print the recipeDivText i get the output like :
Preheat oven to 350&deg;F

Comment: try `Unescape(recipeDivText)` using the above code and it should return the correct result (if it is in fact returning `350&deg;F` and not `350&deg F`) otherwise I'll have to modify it

Comment: The problem is BeautifulSoup returns the HTML contents without unescaping the HTML character references (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) - the above does that

Comment: I can't use that code in mine, its like i just want to escape the HTML characters in the string and display their actual symbol, for that i cant use the code you have mentioned above, i am assuming there must be some simpler solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

In Beautiful Soup 4:

```
my_text = """Preheat oven to 350&deg; F
Welcome to Lorem Ipsum Inc&reg; """

soup = BeautifulSoup(my_text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Result:

```
Preheat oven to 350° F
Welcome to Lorem Ipsum Inc®
```

Comment: Awesome! Consider `print(soup)`, with parenthesis, to be Python 2 & 3 compatible.

Comment: Good call. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere, a program is quoting &deg and &reg without a semicolon.
Try to use "&deg"+";" and "&reg"+";" in your HTML file, if it indeed is an HTML file.
And please explain the context.

Comment: The whole scenario is like this: i am fetching some data from a html page through a url, and I am using the BeautifulSoup module once i receive the data, i receive the data in my variable and then convert it to string format. dataText= str(dataText) and when i print: print dataText i get the ouput like: Preheat oven to 350&deg F i need to get that exact symbol